# How can I show that $\bigcap_{n\geq 0} \sigma(X_n,X_{n+1}...)=\sigma(X)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-calculus

> Let $X$ be a uniformly distributed random variable in $[0,1]$ and define $X_n:=\lfloor 2^nX\rfloor 2^{-n}$ for all $n$. I want to show that $\bigcap_{n\geq 0} \sigma(X_n,X_{n+1}...)=\sigma(X)$.

My idea was the following:

**Proof**:
$\subseteq$ Let me remark that for all $n$, $X_n$ is $\sigma(X)$ measurable since $X_n=f(X)$ where $f(x)=\lfloor 2^nx\rfloor 2^{-n}$ is measurable. Therefore $\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},...)\subset \sigma(X)$ for all $n$ and hence $\bigcap_{n\geq 0} \sigma(X_n,X_{n+1}...)\subseteq\sigma(X)$.

$\supseteq$ Here let me remark that $$\frac{2^nX}{2^n}\leq X_n\leq \frac{2^nX+1}{2^n}$$ where $\frac{2^nX}{2^n}\rightarrow X$ and $\frac{2^nX+1}{2^n}\rightarrow X$, so in particular $X_n\rightarrow X$. But since the limit exists we also know that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}X_n=X$ but we know that $\limsup_n$ is $\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},...)$ measurable. But then this implies that $X$ is $\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},...)$ measurable for all $n$ and hence $\bigcap_{n\geq 0} \sigma(X_n,X_{n+1}...)\supseteq\sigma(X)$.

Does this work?

Comment: Yes. In general, if a random variable $X$ is $\mathcal{G}_i$ measurable $\forall i \in I$, then it is $ \bigcap_{ i \in I} \mathcal{G}_i$ measurable. Can you see why?

Comment: The only thing I would change is $\frac{2^nX+1}{2^n}\rightarrow X\,.$ Apart from that, perfect.

Comment: @AdityaDhawan isn't this the argument I used in $\subseteq$?

Comment: @KurtG. ah sure sorry I didn't noticed that, Thanks!

Comment: @user1294729 No, what you use there is that $\mathcal{G_i}  \subset \sigma(X) \implies \bigcap_{i \in I} \mathcal{G}_i  \subset \sigma(X)$.

Comment: @AdityaDhawan ah sure right sorry, but do you mean that I can use it in the second inclusion ($\supseteq$)? I saw that you edited your first comment and added a question, is it because $\mathcal{G}_i\subset \bigcap_{ i \in I} \mathcal{G}_i$?

Comment: Sorry @AdityaDhawan, OP shows correctly that every $X_n$ is $\sigma(X)$ measurable which correctly implies the inclusion $\subseteq\,.$ For the converse inclusion, OP shows correctly that $X$ is $\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},...)$ measurable.This correctly shows that $\sigma(X)$ is a sub-sigma-algebra of that. Finally since this holds for every $n$ we conclude that $\sigma(X)\subseteq \bigcap_{n\geq 0} \sigma(X_n,X_{n+1}...)\,.$

Comment: @Kurt G I agree that the OPs reasoning is correct. I just remarked that to go from $X$ is $\sigma(X_n, X_{n+1} \cdots)$ measurable to $X$ is $\bigcap_{ n \geq 0 } \sigma(X_{n}, X_{n+1} \cdots  )$ measurable, the OP uses the general fact that $ X $ is $ \mathcal{G}_i $ measurable implies $X$ is $\bigcap_{i \in I}\mathcal{G}_i$ measurable. OP asked how this was different from his reasoning in $\subset$, and  so I clarified. What is the issue?

Comment: @AdityaDhawan I answered your question in the last comment is this true?

Comment: @AdityaDhawan It was unclear to OP and myself what ${\cal G}_i$ was supposed to be and to which part of the proof this refers. Thanks for confirming independently that everything was correct from the beginning.

Comment: Apologies for any confusion, $(\mathcal{G_i})_{i \in I}$ is an arbitrary sequence of sigma algebras, and for this specific question $\mathcal{G_i} = \sigma(X_i, X_{i+1} \ldots)$.

Comment: @user1294729 OP I have clarified what $\mathcal{G}_i$ are; as it stands the reasoning in your comment is false because it is not generally true that $\mathcal{G_i} \subset \bigcap_{ i \in I}{\mathcal{G}_i}$. (The reverse inclusion is true)

Comment: @AdityaDhawan but why is it for a general $\mathcal{G}_i$ true?

Comment: For any measurable set $A$, $X^{-1} (A) \in \mathcal{G_i} \forall i \in I$ which implies $X^{-1}(A) \in \bigcap_{ i \in I} \mathcal{G}_i $.

Comment: @AdityaDhawan I see thanks!